# TSQL Get Date range of last 10 weeks with weeks

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I get a result set in TSQL with a date range of last 10 weeks including the week as column.

```
Date                 WeekNo
2014-11-21           1 
2014-11-22           1 
2014-11-23           1 
....
2014-11-28           2 
2014-11-29           2
```

I was able to put this together with the help of another question but I have failed to include a weekNo in it.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom smalldatetime, @DateTo smalldatetime;
SET @DateFrom= DATEADD(week,-10, GETDATE());
SET @DateTo=GETDATE();
-------------------------------
WITH T(date)
AS
( 
SELECT @DateFrom 
UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date) FROM T WHERE T.date < @DateTo
)
SELECT date FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your above query works, you can just do date arithmetic to get the week:

```
WITH T(date) AS
     (SELECT @DateFrom 
      UNION ALL
     SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date) FROM T WHERE T.date < @DateTo
     )
SELECT date,
       1 + (datediff(day, @DateFrom, date)  / 7)
FROM T
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```